# Substitution with grouped regular expressions by group names in Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

Is there a way to perform a substitution using grouped regular expressions by group names in Ruby?

This is what I've got so far (but as you'll see it lacks some valuable context which renders is useless under pretty common situations):

```
class String

    def scan_in_groups( regexp )
        raise ArgumentError, 'Regexp does not contain any names.' if regexp.names.empty?

        captures = regexp.names.inject( {} ){ |h, n| h[n] = []; h }

        scan( regexp ).each do |match|
            captures.keys.zip( match ).each do |group, gmatch|
                next if !gmatch
                captures[group] << gmatch
            end
        end

        captures.reject { |_, v| v.empty? }
    end

    def sub_in_groups( regexp, group_hash )
        dup.sub_in_groups!( regexp, group_hash )
    end

    def sub_in_groups!( regexp, group_hash )
        scan_in_groups( regexp ).each do |name, value|
            next if !group_hash[name]
            sub!( value.first, group_hash[name] )
        end
        self
    end

end

regexp = /
    \/(?<category>\w+)         # matches category type
    \/                         # path separator
    (?<book-id>\d+)            # matches book ID numbers
    \/                         # path separator
    .*                         # irrelevant
    \/                         # path separator
    chapter-(?<chapter-id>\d+) # matches chapter ID numbers
    \/                         # path separator
    stuff(?<stuff-id>\d+)      # matches stuff ID numbers
/x

path = '/book/12/blahahaha/test/chapter-3/stuff4/12'

p path.scan_in_groups( regexp )
#=> {"category"=>["book"], "book-id"=>["12"], "chapter-id"=>["3"], "stuff-id"=>["4"]}

update = {
    'category'   => 'new-category',
    'book-id'    => 'new-book-id',
    'chapter-id' => 'new-chapter-id',
    'stuff-id'   => '-new-stuff-id'
}

p path.sub_in_groups( regexp, update )
#=> "/new-category/new-book-id/blahahaha/test/chapter-new-chapter-id/stuff-new-stuff-id/12"

p '/12/book/12/blahahaha/test/chapter-3/stuff4/12'.sub_in_groups( regexp, update )
#=> /new-book-id/new-category/12/blahahaha/test/chapter-new-chapter-id/stuff-new-stuff-id/12
```

What I need is a solution that preserves the context of the Regexp matches and obly substitutes them so that the end result would be:

`#=> /12/new-category/new-book-id/blahahaha/test/chapter-new-chapter-id/stuff-new-stuff-id/12`

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of doing it would be something like this

```
def substitute!(regexp, string,updates)
  if match = regexp.match(string)
    keys_in_order = updates.keys.sort_by {|k| match.offset(k)}.reverse
    keys_in_order.each do |k|
      offsets_for_group = match.offset(k)
      string[offsets_for_group.first...offsets_for_group.last] = updates[k]
    end
  end
end
```

This modifies the string in place.

When you have the match data, then `match.offset(capture_name)` returns the beginning and the end offsets of that group, which this code then uses to do the updates. You need to do the subsitutions from the end of the string first, so that they don't shift the offsets.

If you only need to change one group you can do

```
x = "/foo/bar/baz"
x[/(?<group>bar)/, 'group'] = 'new'
# x is now '/foo/bar/baz'
```

Comment: You're missing the "updates" argument but other than that it seems to work just fine, thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Are the words to be changed the same?

```
replacements = [ ["category", "new-category"], ["book-id", "new-book-id"], ["chapter-id", "new-chapter-id"], ["stuff-id", "-new-stuff-id"] ]
replacements.each {|replacement| str.gsub!(replacement[0], replacement[1])}
```